# Open External URL when scroll down in Fullpage js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I have added three horizontal slides with full-page js, but I want to open the External URL when I scroll down to the last section. I have added a scroll function that counts the scrolls of mouse and its work in all pages, but not on the full-page slider page.

```
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st < lastScrollTop){
        console.log('up 1');
    }
    else
        {
            console.log('down 1');
        }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Value console on all pages except the page where I added Full page js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onLeave callback when you leave the second last page

```
onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){
    if(destination.index == lastPage){
        //open new Page
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me more I didn't get

Comment: you can check the demo https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/XbPNQv

Comment: And `lastPage` should be the index of your last section, which instead of hardcoding it, it can be done like this too:  `destination.index === document.querySelectorAll('.fp-section').length-1`